# Cant get my array to load in listview and i have no idea why

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview

I am trying to extract data from a csv file, into an array and then display that array in a listview.  I am nearly there (after lots of searching/google time...new to Java/android), but cant work out what i am doing wrong.

I have a text file I am loading, then I am extracting the contents into a string array called splitdata.  I want the splitdata array to be displayed in the listview.

My code is:

```
   try {
    File myFile = new File("/sdcard/file.txt");
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(fIn));
    String aDataRow = "";
    String aBuffer = "";
    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
        aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
    }

    //      String loadeddata = aBuffer;
    String[] splitdata = aBuffer.split(",");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_item, splitdata);

    adapter.clear();
    adapter.addAll(splitdata);
    lvlogbook.setAdapter(adapter);
            myReader.close();
```

When i load the activity i just get the blank listview displayed.  Help well received please (I have tested the array in a textview and the data i want is being separated out, i think the problem is with how i am trying to fill the adapter with my data).

Thank you for any help.

Andy

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See notifyDataSetChanged().  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged().  You should also use a StringBuilder for aBuffer.  Using String will potentially cause a lot of garbage collection and is inefficient.

Comment: thanks, could you expand alittle on use of a stringbuffer?

Comment: A String is immutable.  Once created, it cannot be modified.  Any change will create a new String.  You do this multiple times in a loop and you generate lots of Strings which have to be garbage collected afterwards.  StringBuilder avoids this.  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(firstLine);sb.append(secondLine); etc then use sb.toString() when you are finished building it.

Comment: thankyou, i will modify my code accordingly.  just got to get the list view working now...

Comment: You're welcome.  http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Comment: good link/tutorial, sadly i am still at a complete loss why my array isnt populating the listview?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have a TextView with specific id that ArrayAdapter expects by default.

Try default layout:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, splitdata);
```

Or try another constructor providing your actual ID of the TextView, e.g.

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_item, R.id.YOURTEXTVIEWID, splitdata);
```

Comment: sorry, am i being dull, do i need a textview within the listview to get this working?

Comment: i do have a grid_item xml file that the arrayadapter is calling, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you need to have a text view inside your item layout. `ArrayAdapter` will call `setText` for this view when needed.

Comment: thank you. sorry for the simple question, but how do i add the textview into the listview?

Comment: Not into the ListView, but into your R.layout.grid_item. This is item layout you defined yourself, right? You can change whatever you want there, so you can add a TextView. Or just try the first option with android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to make sure that you are on the right way. Maybe it will be enough.

Comment: I get the same result with android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 as I do with my own xml file (which does have a textview in it).  I think the issue is to do with how i am populating the array/string from the csv file and not necessarily the listview itself?

Comment: Well, it is also possible :)
It is easy to check, try this: `String[] splitdata = new String[] {"one", "two", "three" }` and if you'll see these strings in the list - no problems with the adapter then. 
I'm actually not sure about your `adapter.clear();` and `adapter.addAll(splitdata);`, both look unnecessary.

Comment: I tried the string as you suggested and i still get nothing in my listview. I will post my xml file below.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to display several strings in each row, right? Bad idea, it will not work with ArrayAdapter in this way, you rather need your custom adapter to support this or better something like TableLayout. I also tried `simple_list_item1` in a small test project http://pastebin.com/zf0NMpgd it works fine. Are you sure you have copied all related sources?

Comment: thanks. maybe tablelayout will do what i want then, should i put the table layout in the listview xml file or just bin the listview idea and just use table layout? i was hoping to have a scrollable table displayed in my activity.

Comment: Try `ScrollView` and `TableLayout` inside. It should be pretty good as a concept proof, but I'm not sure if it will be ok for production in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This is my grid_item.xml file that i am calling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


      <TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:text="row_id"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="300dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:text="col_1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="180dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:text="col_2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="180dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:text="col_3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:width="100dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

All i get when i load the activity with the listview in is just the toast popup that i have to catch the exception.   I am confused why my listview isnt working.  What have i missed?  If i comment out the adapter clear and adapter addAll on the adapter then the activity just crashes on launch (stops unexpectedly).